# Add "m" modifier to qr pattern passed as parameter

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to be able to add the "m" modifier to a regex that was passed to a function.

The following test script demonstrates what I'm trying to do

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.16.3;

use Test::More tests => 3;

my $no_m_modifier_re   = qr{^line1\n^line2};
my $with_m_modifier_re = qr{^line1\n^line2}m;

my $text = <<'EoM';
line1
line2
line3
EoM

unlike( $text, $no_m_modifier_re, 'Text will not match ^ that is equivalent to \A' );
like( $text, $with_m_modifier_re, 'Text will match ^ with m modifier' );

# This fails to add the m modifier to the subexpression
my $add_m_modifier_re = qr{(?m)$no_m_modifier_re};
#my $add_m_modifier_re = qr{(?m:$no_m_modifier_re)};    # Experimented other syntax, with same result
#my $add_m_modifier_re = qr{$no_m_modifier_re}m;
#my $add_m_modifier_re = qr{(?^m:$no_m_modifier_re)};    # suggested by mob, didn't work.

like( $text, $add_m_modifier_re, 'Want this to match, but it fails to add m modifier to subexpression' );
```

The results are

```
$ prove -v m_modifier.pl
m_modifier.pl ..
1..3
ok 1 - Text will not match ^ that is equivalent to \A
ok 2 - Text will match ^ with m modifier
not ok 3 - Want this to match, but it fails to add m modifier to subexpression

#   Failed test 'Want this to match, but it fails to add m modifier to subexpression'
#   at m_modifier.pl line 25.
#                   'line1
# line2
# line3
# '
#     doesn't match '(?^:(?m)(?^:^line1\n^line2))'
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 3.
Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/3 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
m_modifier.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 3 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  3
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=1, Tests=3,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.04 usr  0.01 sys +  0.14 cusr  0.05 csys =  0.24 CPU)
Result: FAIL
```

As you can see, I experimented with different syntax for adding the m modifier, but none of them appear to apply to the original pattern.

Any ideas?

This is under Perl 5.16.3.  I have not tried more modern versions.

Comment: @zdim I'm honestly just looking for ANY way to force the passed qr regex to utilize the /m modifier.  If I have to hack it in some way, that's what I'll do.

Alternatively, a way to inspect the RE to see if it has the /m modifier could also be helpful since I can put the burden on the user of the method instead to always include it or an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried `qr{(?^m:$no_m_modifier_re)}` like you suggested, but it still fails. The test reports `doesn't match '(?^u:(?^m:(?^u:^line1\n^line2)))'`

You are trying to modify a compiled pattern. For that, you need the following:

```perl
use re qw( is_regexp regexp_pattern );

my $re = qr/^line1\n^line2/;

my ($pat, $mods) =
   is_regexp($re)
      ? regexp_pattern($re)
      : ( $re, "" );

$mods .= 'm' if $mods !~ /m/;

$re = eval("qr/\$pat/$mods")
   or die($@);  # Should never happen.
```

It also works with uncompiled patterns, resulting in a compiled pattern with minimal `(?:)` nesting.

```
The result for   "abc"       is   qr/abc/m    which stringifies as   (?^um:abc)
The result for   qr/abc/     is   qr/abc/m    which stringifies as   (?^um:abc)
The result for   qr/abc/m    is   qr/abc/m    which stringifies as   (?^um:abc)
The result for   qr/abc/s    is   qr/abc/sm   which stringifies as   (?^ums:abc)
The result for   qr/abc/sm   is   qr/abc/sm   which stringifies as   (?^ums:abc)
```

Comment: @Miller consistency. I use low-precedence `or` and `and` for flow control.

Comment: duh, don't even need to check for defined. `qr//` will always return a true value. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you need to change a `qr`-ed expression, which is a [regex object](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) which

> ...magically differs from a string containing the same characters: `ref(qr/x/)` returns "Regexp"; however, dereferencing it is not well defined...

I can't find a way to change it, or add a flag to it (other than to edit its stringification).

However, if you can change the approach so to define (non-`qr`) variables to start with and then later `qr`-them as needed then it works as desired

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.16.3;

use Test::More tests => 3;

my $no_m_modifier_re   = q{^line1\n^line2};  # not qr{} but q{}; just a string

my $text = <<'EoM';
line1
line2
line3
EoM

unlike( $text, qr{$no_m_modifier_re}, 'Text does not match ^ equivalent to \A' );

like(   $text, qr{$no_m_modifier_re}m, 'Text matches with the modifier' );

like(   $text, qr{(?m)$no_m_modifier_re}, 'Text matches with the modifier' );
```

Along with strings one can set up `qr`-ed variables as well, for convenience,<sup>†</sup> but the main idea is that the user forms a regex pattern along with needed fine-tuning, for example by modifiers.

---

<sup>†</sup> If either may get passed around they can be told apart by `ref`

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there. In Perl 5.16.3, it's

```
qr/(?^m:pattern)/   # equiv to   /pattern/m
```

In earlier versions, it would be something like

```
qr/(?m-xis:pattern)/   # equiv to  /pattern/m
qr/(?ix-ms:patterm)/   # equiv to  /pattern/ix
```

This won't work for all regexp modifiers. In particular, the `/g` modifier can't be emulated this way.

Demo:

```
$ perl -E 'say 0 + ("CAT" =~ /cat/)'
0
$ perl -E 'say 0 + ("CAT" =~ /(?^i:cat)/)'
1
```

Update: found the docs [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlre#Extended-Patterns). Too long to excerpt, but they provide a much broader and deeper understanding of "embedded pattern-match modifiers" than my answer.

Comment: I tried ```qr{(?^m:$no_m_modifier_re)}``` like you suggested, but it still fails.  The test reports ```doesn't match '(?^u:(?^m:(?^u:^line1\n^line2)))'```

Comment: I think the problem is that they have a `qr`-ed pattern that need be changed, and in my tests this still doesn't make it... like `perl -wE'$_=q(aAa); $re = qr{a}; say for /(?^i)($re)/g'` prints `aa` (no `A`). With `$re = q{a}` (not `qr`) it works and prints `aAa`

Comment: Re "*This won't work for all regexp modifiers*", It works for all modifiers that affect the regex (which I would call regex modifiers), but it doesn't work for the operator modifiers. `g` for `m//` and `s///`, `r` for `s///`, `e` for `s///`. It's no surprise that you can't use modifiers in a regex that don't affect the regex.

Comment: `$add_m_modifier_re` is a `qr` construction of a `qr` construction? I think that's the problem.  A simpler `$add_m_modifier_re = qr{(?m)^line1\n^line2}` ought to work.

Comment: "_is a `qr` construction of a `qr` construction?_" -- yes, that's the problem, as shown in a comment

Comment: There function in `re::` that will get split a compiled regex into a pattern and its flags, which could help that nesting.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach has been broken since 5.14 inclusive.

Replace:

```
# This fails to add the m modifier to the subexpression
my $add_m_modifier_re = qr{(?m)$no_m_modifier_re};
```

`(?^u:(?m)(?^u:^line1\n^line2))`

With:

```
my $add_m_modifier = $no_m_modifier_re;
$add_m_modifier =~ s/:/m:/;
my $add_m_modifier_re = qr{$add_m_modifier};
```

`(?^u:(?^um:^line1\n^line2))`

I never worked with Perl so don't blame me! ;D

https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta#(?%5E...)-construct-signifies-default-modifiers

Comment: It's a hack, but yes, the following does work ```my $add_m_modifier_re = ( map qr/$_/m, $no_m_modifier_re =~ s/:/m:/r )[0];```

Comment: This is the only way I found to change a `qr`-ed pattern, to edit its stringification